# Access Denied accessing serial using Native call

Tags: java, android, serialization, native

Please bear with me since I'm new to both serial and android.  I try to open serial port to send data.  So I connect my android device with USB-serial adapter to a printer, I get access denied error when make the call below.

```
fileDescriptor = open("/dev/ttyUSB0", O_RDWR | flag);
if(fileDescriptor==-1)
{
    LOGE("inside OpenSerialPort()- cannot open port");
    LOGE("inside OpenSerialPort()- errno=%s", strerror(errno));
    return -1;
}
```

There is online post solution for different serial port that it needs to set the user permission with the following suggestion.

```
chmod o+rw /dev/ttyS0
chmod o+rw /dev/ttyS1
```

Where can i add this type of permission to my project?  Is it in native call layer or java code layer or in android manifest xml?  prefer to set this permission programmatically.

thanks.

Answer (score 0):

you have to open a console with

```
adb shell
```

and from the console type the command:

```
chmod o+rw /dev/ttyUSB0
```

or

```
chmod 755 /dev/ttyUSB0
```

Comment: Hi Lino.  Thanks for your answer.  However I was looking for how to do this in code, but not terminal cmd.  It seems Linux has C method called chmod().

Comment: Now i'm getting different error so I will create new question.